# HTML5 localstorage adding in double quotes

Tags: json, html, local-storage

I'm currently assigning the value of a field to a variable:

```
userName = document.getElementById('userName').value;
```

Then assigning that variable to localstorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('userName', JSON.stringify(userName));
```

Retrieving that item here:

```
var retrievedUserName = localStorage.getItem('userName');
```

Then trying to output the contents of the item into a HTML div:

```
document.getElementById("response-heading-name2").innerHTML = retrievedUserName;
```

...but when I check the HTML, it's outputting the string with double quotes around it: "My name"

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how I can stop the double quotes from appearing?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This has nothing to do with local storage.

The quotes are added when you convert the data structure to JSON with `JSON.stringify`.

You should convert the JSON back to a JavaScript data structure with `JSON.parse` after you retrieve it from local storage.

---

The point of using JSON is to ensure that what you store is a string because local storage can only store strings.

Since you are getting the value of an input, you know that it will be a string. So you could dispense with JSON altogether and not `JSON.stringify` it in the first place.

Comment: Exactly, I realized it too as I was reading the first paragraph. Nice.

Answer (score 3):

localStorage always store the string data with double quotes, when you are retrieving the same data you will get with double quotes. So just use `JSON.parse` to fix it.

```
var retrievedUserName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userName'));
```

Comment: Stringify goes the wrong way. You need to use parse. (Like I said in my answer from over five years ago).

Comment: "localStorage always store the string data with double quotes" — No it won't. It will store the strings you put in it. If the strings contain double quotes, then the data in localStorage will. If they don't, it won't.

Comment: If the strings contain double quotes, then the data in localStorage will. If they don't, it won't -- No I passed the value as parameter its stored with double quotes.